# How can I make a context manager returning a generator exit successfully when not fully consuming the generator?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I'm reading a CSV file using the `with`-block in Python. This emulates a file being opened (`__enter__`), the lines of the file being generated on demand (`yield (...)`) and the file being closed (`__exit__`).

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_file():
    print('__enter__')
    yield (f'line {i}' for i in (1, 2, 3))
    print('__exit__')
```

I want to read the lines of this CSV and want to return a model for each row. So I'm doing something like that:

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

def create_models():
    with open_file() as f:
        for line in f:
            yield Model(int(line.split(' ')[-1]))
```

If I run through the whole file, it will call both `__enter__` and `__exit__` callbacks:

```py
def main1():
    for model in create_models():
        print(model.value)

main1()
# __enter__
# 1
# 2
# 3
# __exit__
```

However, if I don't need all models from the file, it'll not call the `__exit__` callback:

```py
def main2():
    for model in create_models():
        print(model.value)
        if model.value % 2 == 0:
            break

main2()
# __enter__
# 1
# 2
```

How can I implement a context manager that exits even if I don't iterate over the whole child generator? Is it even possible?

Note that, in this example, I can't change the `open_file` context manager, since in my code it's the [`open` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) from Python (I used `open_file` here just to be a minimal and reproducible example).

What I want to do is something similar to `Stream`s in Dart:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Model {
  final int value;

  const Model(this.value);
}

void main() {
  File('file.csv')
    .openRead()
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const LineSplitter())
    .map((line) => int.parse(line.split(',')[1]))
    .map((value) => Model(value))
    .takeWhile((model) => model.value % 2 == 0)
    .forEach((model) {
      print(model.value);
    });
}
```

This would close the file successfully, even if I don't consume all lines from it (`takeWhile`). Since my Python codebase is all synchronous code, I'd like to avoid introducing `async` and `await`, because it would take too long to refactor.

Comment: The context manager created by `open()` handles this. So if you're actually using `open()`, you don't need to do anythiing.

Comment: A real context manager should have separate `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods. When you leave the context, the `__exit__()` method is called automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that `'__exit__'` is printed, change `open_file` to:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_file():
    print('__enter__')
    try:
        yield (f'line {i}' for i in (1, 2, 3))
    finally:
        print('__exit__')
```

The reason is that `break` causes the generator to raise a `GeneratorExit` exception which makes `open_file` skip `print('__exit__')` unless you handle it or add a `finally`.

This common pattern of `try: yield resource; finally: cleanup` is shown in the first example of the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.